# is it good to go for interfaces to communicate between fragment and fragment activity

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, responsive-design

in my fragment activity i need to display some 3 fragment at a time, one fragment contains set of buttons, another contains list etc...

If a click occurs on button, then i need to change the list fragment and show the details. 
To communicate "show detail fragment to parent" its better to keep an interface and register for it and when anyone clicks on button simply notify click happened or should i create the fragment activity method showdetailsfragment via object of parent activity?

is it better to create interface and notify when event occurs from fragment? or use parent object to communicate or any other best alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks):

"In some cases, you might need a fragment to share events with the activity. A good way to do that is to define a callback interface inside the fragment and require that the host activity implement it. When the activity receives a callback through the interface, it can share the information with other fragments in the layout as necessary."